# RGB colors changing on including alpha while drawing on Buffered Image

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt, alpha

I am trying to write a Buffered Image and read its colors back. Although alpha remain same, the RGB colors seem to change. I am unable to understand the reason behind this. Any help on fixing this is appreciated. I need the image to return exactly same color as what I wrote.

```
    try {
        BufferedImage img=new BufferedImage(256, 256,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics graphics =
                img.createGraphics();
        int r=45;int g=45; int b=100; int a=50;
        System.out.println("Red  "+r+"   Green "+g+"    Blue "+b+"   alpha "+a);

        graphics.setColor(new Color(r,g,b,a));
        graphics.fillRect(10,10, 40, 40);

        Integer i=img.getRGB(23,23);
        Color c=new Color(i,true);

        System.out.println("Going to read color back");
        System.out.println("Red  "+c.getRed()+"   Green "+c.getGreen()+"    Blue "+c.getBlue()+"   alpha "+c.getAlpha());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output of the program:
Red  45   Green 45    Blue 100   alpha 50

Going to read color back

Red  46   Green 46    Blue 102   alpha 50

Comment: When you fillRect with alpha color it mixes with background color

Comment: There is no color in background. You can check my code! I think there is something wrong in BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB

Comment: Why do you need this??? Use an array instead if you want exact colors!!!

Comment: I store data on "map tiles" by identifying unique colors. Now if I add alpha, I can have 256*256*256*256 unique color and hence that may identities.

Answer (score 1):

Below code should be added before drawing anything in image with alpha if you want to secure source color. This solved my problem.

```
graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC));
```

[Alpha Composite Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html)
[Alpha Composite tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html)